# clearing user input buffer in c / c++

Tags: c++, c, input, buffer

I'd like to clear input buffer, but do not know how, heres the code please try for yourself:

```
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    do {
        Sleep(500);
        if (kbhit())
            cout << (char) getch() << endl;
    } while(1);
}
```

If I spam-press keyboard, letters would print one by one, each delayed by 500ms.

> How do I clear whole input buffer and only one letter will appear even if I press multiple

Comment: I'm fairly sure that `kbhit` and `getch` are not available from `<windows.h>`.  What is your real list of includes?

Comment: does it really matter? i included <conio.h> and <iostream>, but windows is required for the delay, now can you help me please ?

Comment: What input buffer when you're using `getch` and not `getchar`? `getch` merely gets the character value, directly, without waiting for any enter key-press or anything. Edit: Nevermind...

Answer (score 0):

So you are writing a Windows console app. Not DOS and not cross-platform compatible.

You could use the Windows Console functions. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

In particular you can get the handle with GetStdHandle, then WaitForSingleObject on the handle. Probably with a 500 ms timeout instead of your current Sleep.

Then you should be able to ReadConsole to read all of the input that has been buffered since the last time you read it. If you want the first character or the last character you would just take that one.

There are a lot of details you'd need to add in to all that to make it actually work.

Comment: wouldnt that be more complicated than the method described above, wich uses getch() and kbhit() ? or is there something im missing?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of depends on how exactly you want the behaviour to be. Since you haven't specified it in detail, here are two that I'll offer:

```
// ...
do {
    Sleep( 500 );
    if ( kbhit( ) ) {
        cout << (char) getch( ) << endl;
        while ( kbhit( ) )
            getch( );
    }
} while ( 1 );
// ...
```

The addition of the `while` loop inside there, clears the remaining keystrokes inside the buffer. It does that by checking for the condition if there is a remaining keystroke, in which case discarding it.

While this seems to be what you want from the way you've asked, I would like to suggest the following, which would feel much smoother in my opinion:

```
// ...
do {
    cout << (char) getch( ) << endl;
    Sleep( 500 );
    while ( kbhit( ) )
        getch( );
} while ( 1 );
// ...
```

The way it gets smoother won't get much recognized with a delay like `500`, but raise it to `2500` and you may understand what I mean. On the first version, your keystrokes will appear delayed by `0 ~ 500/2500` milliseconds all the time; while on the second version, your keystrokes will appear immediately if they are to appear (i.e. were pressed out of the cooldown).

Comment: Thank you man, that was exactly what I was looking for, ill just explain you why i'd need first option. i am doing a snake game (first ever bigger project) and i want snake to keep moving even if key wasnt pressed (thats why if(kbhit()) ), cant wait for input becuase while waiting for input snake (frames) doesnt move at all. Also could you suggest me any big console project that'd be fun to take on? regards.

Comment: @gsdag No problem bro. Expand your snake project into a multiplayer (two players that'll play using the same keyboard, WASD and arrows), design the gameplay first; or a tic-tac-toe, with solo and multiplayer options, solo being against a never-losing AI (not impossible, I personally know algorithms that prevent loss in any case). Or something else, I don't know.

Comment: Yeah I've already done the tic tac toe one, but the snake idea is pretty darn nice! what else can I program C++, because I've only been taught console programs, can I make games / aplications / anything else useful with c++??